# Error trying to compile an example from newly added Arduino menu library

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd, library, compile

I added the ArduinoMenu library https://github.com/neu-rah/ArduinoMenu and when I try to compile one of the examples, I get following error.

> Using library LiquidCrystal at version 1.0.5 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560.

How can I fix this?

Comment: We need the full error output, not just the last couple lines that happened to be visible. If you were observant you would have seen that there is a scroll bar on the right side of the black console window at the bottom of the Arduino IDE window that indicates you can scroll up to see more text. Spend some time reading those errors and doing research to see if you can figure out what's wrong on your own. After that if you still can't solve the problem click the button on the right side of the orange bar after an error "Copy error messages" then edit your question to include the full error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add your library in the library folder. Below is the path of that folder. It will help you.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries`

Comment: You should never install a library to the Arduino IDE installation folder because it will be lost if you update to a new version of the IDE. If you're doing a manual library installation you should always install them to the `libraries` subfolder of the sketchbook folder. The location of the sketchbook folder can be found at **File > Preferences > Sketchbook location**.

Comment: @per1234 Yes, you're right. But everyone uses this method and it's working fine.

Comment: @per1234... This is the simplest way to add library by just copy and paste.

Comment: there are better places for libraries. the install folder is for core, and customizing it is asking for trouble

Comment: @Hasan if by "everyone" you mean unfortunate beginners who found some bad advice on the internet. And no, it's not working fine, as I already explained.

Comment: @karanrp it's no more simple than installing to the sketchbook folder and much less so when you update and find all your 3rd party and custom libraries have disappeared.

Comment: please install from arduino ide library manager

Answer (score 0):

Can you compile the LCD example for that board? 
just to make sure you have LiquidCrystal library ok.

Then tell us what was the example? There are hardware specific examples.

Also try to compile the serial menu example, just to make sure that ArduinoMenu library is ok for your board.